# Stuck in GRUB on Mac mini booted with ubuntu ONLY. corrupt partitions

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub

To start, I am NOT familiar at all with Linux. I needed it for school, and it was having issues booting onto an older intel Mac mini (2018). The Mac was 100% excellent and running Ventura perfectly. After the install of Ubuntu, Ventura was gone and the partitions that were originally made, were gone as well. Ubuntu did not run well and I went to repartition the drive (linux terminal is NOT the same as Mac...I learned quickly). Well, now it is stuck in GRUB and won't boot at all from any USB (I have the original Ubuntu and a Mac Ventura) both are not working. GRUB recognizes the Ubuntu boot usb but when I try to boot it in GRUB it says "error you need to load the kernel first". Upon doing -ls for each partition and drive, it shows that (hd1,1) is the only one that has a file system (FAT) other than the boot usb which is (hd0) and says that it is an iso file system with Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on it. I really want to get back to Ventura but it seems all the "Mac" characteristics and functions are totally gone.

UPDATE: the kernel that is missing is `vmlinuz`. I can almost get to being able to boot. also, the only bootable file that GRUB can mention is memtest86+.bin. if I could get the `vmlinuz` downloaded I think I could get it to boot.

Anyone know how to download vmlinuz kernel in GRUB? is it even possible?

ANOTHER UPDATE:

This is what I ran:
`grub> ls (hd0)/boot  (grub prints) grub/ memtest86+.bin`

this seems like a boot kernel from the usb download (hd0). Is there a way to access this? I might just be so tired of staring at the screen that Im missing it completely.